# Mistake while calculating the maximum pairwise product

Tags: c++, product, pairwise

Trying to write the function to calculate the maximum pairwise product in C++, but for some reason the computation is wrong. Could anyone review my code please?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;
using std::cin; 
using std::cout; 
using std::max;

int MaxPairWiseProduct(const vector<int>& numbers) {
  int product = 0;
  int n =  numbers.size();
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {
      product = max(product, numbers[i] * numbers[j]);
    }
  }
  return product;
}

int main() {
   int n;
   cin >> n;
   vector<int> numbers(n);
   for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
     cin >> numbers[i];
   }

   int product = MaxPairWiseProduct(numbers);
   cout << product << "\n";
   return 0;
}
```

The question is resolved - basically, the mistake that occurred was integer overflow, therefore after compilation it didn't output the value properly. The solution is using the int64_t type when computing the product and storing the result.

Comment: Check this out: https://dev.widemeadows.de/2017/08/23/use-your-conda-environment-in-jupyter-notebooks/

Comment: Do you know how I can fix this, if my Kernel is running? http://joxi.ru/1A5o7gBsnxW16m I tried to restart, but it comes to the same place

Comment: Try setting product = INT_MIN

Comment: Please edit the question adding the expected results given some test inputs. Even better, you should roll back the edits to your original (and completely different) question and ask a **new** question.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again, but it's customary not to modify the *question* when OP's problem is solved, but rather to add an *answer* (which [you can easily write](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)) and [*accept*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it. BTW, please note that, while your algorithm is O(N^2), ther's also an [O(N) solution](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iIDGKP5y4Jl7BRtn).